Is it defensible to combine total scores from separate assessments to assess intervention gains?
I have two assessments, each with 28 multiple-choice items, and a total of sample size of about 180 students. Both assessments were given to students at pre-assessment and once again at post-assessment after an intervention.  The assessments were identical at both time points  with some items shuffled around to minimize memory effects. In our intervention study, students were randomly assigned to control and experimental conditions.
After assessing intervention gains separately for each assessment, I wanted to compute an average score from the two assessments and examine gains this way, as I believe the average scores are more reliable since more data go into them. Further, theoretically, I believe the assessments tap into related constructs of knowledge. However, I would like to justify the decision of combining by doing the following, and I'd love to get your opinions on whether what I've done is defensible, and whether there's something else I should consider before moving forward with examining students' gains from the intervention using averaged scores.

I examined Pearson correlations between two assessment total scores during both assessment periods. They were .61 at pre-assessment and .62 at post-assessment.
I computed a tetrachoric correlation matrix (tetrachoric because items were scored as correct/incorrect) and there was no clear pattern that items within one assessment were more highly correlated than items across assessments. To be honest, it is also really hard to stare at this correlation matrix for long because there’re so many items.  So then I turned to the next step, which is CFA.
I conducted two CFAs: Model 1: where I put all 56 items into a single-factor model.  As a side note, I used DWLS estimator in lavaan because items were binary.  Model 2 where 28 items go into one factor for assessment A and the remaining goes to second factor for assessment B.  I then compared the model fit between the two using lavTestLRT function and saw that one-model factor has a significantly better fit than a two-factor model at both time points.

I have two questions:

Do you think that the analyses and results shown above provide sufficient justification to use average scores and allow me to examine intervention gains that way? If the answer is no, what else should I be thinking and doing?
If possible, can you confirm that lavTestLRT function can be used for model comparison for models with binary data?  I don’t see why not, but I wanted to confirm since this is my first time working with binary data.



Assessing intervention gains by computing a pre-treatment average or sum score and a post-treatment average or sum score always makes sense IMHO. Unless you constructed a very bad set of items.

It is very common for assessments over time to be strongly correlated, but it is certainly no pre-condition for meaningfully comparing average scores between timepoints. Very small correlations could simply indicate treatment was not equally effective for different persons in the dataset. That does not mean the comparison of mean or sum scores is invalid.
Your question 1. could be answered with a complete book about psychometrics, i.e., the field that studies how we can be sure we measure the non-directly observable human characteristic we are interested in. You probably know where to find those.
But I can provide some basic advice:

It would be good to show that the item scores are strongly associated within each measurement occasion. You can do that using CFA, a separate one for each timepoint. Good fit would indicate (not prove) that the items measure a similar construct. Stronger associations between items are considered better, because the average or sum score will then be a more reliable measure of the thing you want to measure.
(Note that very strong correlations (e.g., .90 or higher) would not be so good anymore, because this likely indicates you have been repeating the exact same question 28 times, and asking just 1 or 2 questions would have sufficed.)

In my experience, it is difficult to obtain good model fit with 28 items and 1 factor. In any case, model fit with 56 items and 1 factor will be much worse. There is not much interesting or surprising about finding that a 2-factor model fits 56 items better than a 1-factor model; I would almost always expect this to be the case. Further, better fit for one model than the other does not mean any of the models fits well. Hence my recommendation to inspect model fit separately per measurement occasion.

If you obtain well-fitting models at both occasions (i.e., strong associations between items and factors, good model fit), the average or sum scores will be reliable measures at each measurement occasion. You have not yet proven that validity is good, for how to show that you best consult psychometrics books.
IMHO, it is not even completely necessary to have high correlations between items. Indicators of socio-economic status (e.g., housing prices in neighbourhood where you live, educational level, yearly wage) might not correlate strongly, but averaged or summed still yield very useful measures. They are simply somewhat less reliable, due to lower correlations.

Some might then argue that you should not use (observed) average or sum scores if you are also using CFA, and you should use latent scores. I.e., you should assess the intervention effect with a) factor scores derived from the two CFAs, or b) a single longitudinal CFA model, where you compare the factor means between the two timepoints. The latter would give you everything you want in one single model, but might be a bit challenging to set up.
I would agree that factor scores can be used, but IMHO average or sum scores are simple, easy to understand measures. Use of factor scores, or a longitudinal CFA model, might make things unnecessarily complex. Latent factor scores tend to correlate very strongly (>.90) with observed average or sum scores anyway (Google Scholar can help you find studies that show this), so one could argue they are more or less interchangeable.



Yes, you can use the lavTestLRT for that, but I doubt the relevance of the test you performed in this context.

